Specifying different error behaviors for different S3 origins on CloudFront
I have the following situation and I need help on how to proceed:

I have a multi-page website in a private S3 bucket. It uses an OAI to allow a CloudFront distribution to distribute this website at example.com.

I have a single-page application hosted in another private S3 bucket. It uses an OAI to allow the same CloudFront distribution to distribute the website at example.com/app. The CloudFront distribution contains an "Additional Behavior" which directs requests to the path /app* to the app's S3 bucket.


My problem lies in the fact that I need different error behaviors for both origins. The first origin, the S3 bucket containing the website, returns 404.html on 404 Not Found. This is simple enough to do; I can specify the error response for the distribution to use this filepath. The problem is that the second origin, the SPA served at example.com/app, needs to return its index.html document on 404, since it is an SPA. I cannot specify error handling in CloudFront on a per-origin basis.
I have two known workarounds to this issue:

Use the static website feature on S3 for the SPA and specify its error document there.
Create a Lambda@Edge function to somehow customize the error handling behavior for URIs of /app*.

My understanding is that it is recommended to avoid the static website feature of S3 and instead use an OAI to CloudFront, so I'd prefer to implement option 2. I am having trouble writing the necessary function however, and I can't find any examples where someone has implemented something similar. Any guidance or help on this issue would be appreciated - either in terms of accomplishing the above or if there is a superior strategy altogether.

You can keep your S3 origin as a bucket, without using the static website endpoint, and use CloudFront Functions to rewrite all requests to index.html for your SPA. This would replace your custom error page handling. Something like this should work:
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    request.uri = '/index.html';
    return request;
}

